# Presentation complex of a finite perfect group and its features

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, gn.general-topology, cw-complexes

Let $G$ be a finite perfect group and consider $X_G$, its presentation complex. I have the following questions:

1. Is there any special property of $X_G$ due to the group's perfectness?
2. What can we say about $H_2(X_G;\mathbb{Z})$, is it non-trivial free sometimes?

Any suggestions will be really helpful. Thanks!

Comment: What is the definition of $X_G$? I've never heard of the "representation complex" of a group, and I couldn't find anything with a quick Google search.

Comment: That's the presentation complex.

Comment: I do apologize. I have edited. Thanks!

Comment: 1. Since $G$ is perfect, $H_1(X_G,\mathbb{Z})=0$ by Hurewicz.
2. $H_2(X_G,\mathbb{Z})$ is always free (since $X_G$ is 2-dimensional) and can certainly be non-trivial. For a silly example, consider the presentation $\langle a\mid a,a\rangle$ of the trivial group, which has $X_G$ homeomorphic to the 2-sphere.

Comment: In fact, $H_2$ is easy to compute using Euler characteristic. If the presentation has $m$ generators and $n$ relations then $\chi(X_G)=1-m+n$ and so $H_2$ must have rank $n-m$.

Comment: One final comment. Of course, one should choose the most efficient possible presentation for a given group. It seems to be an open question whethe or not every finite simple group has a presentation with $m=n$ -- see this answer and the references therein:   https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3273061/perfect-finite-groups-with-balanced-presentations .